# Assigning a subscribe value from an API into a global variable

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm looking to allow the data that I called from an API to be used as a global variable in Typescript. I understand that the nature of subscribe() won't allow for such a thing and I'm wondering if there is a workaround for it.

Below is the API

```
      getResultCount(category:any):Observable<any>
 
     {
        let cat = category;
        return this._http.get(`${this.castapi}/cat/${cat}`);
      }
```

and this is to call the API

```
  getResult(){
    this.service.getResultCount("Horror").subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data, "Output");
      this.resultCount = res.data; // value is only stored within subscribe()
    });
  }

  category: any[] = [
    {
      "name" : "book",
      "value" : this.resultCount   // undefined
    }
  ];
```

Comment: Sure this is possible, and your code actually *does* store the value on the `this` instance. But the endeavour is pointless, since you never know when (or whether) the variable will have been updated, and you cannot react to changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer is: Don't. Once you go with Observables, try to stay there, and use AsyncPipe. If I wanted to convert the array into a record, for example, I'd recommend

```js
const counts$: Observable<Record<string, number>>;
const countsListing$: Observable<string>:

constructor(
  public service: Service
) {
  this.counts$ = concat(
    of({}), // start with empty object until we get service result
    this.service.getCountData().pipe(
      map(this.countDataToRecord)
  ).pipe(
    shareReplay(1) // do it once, not once per subscriber
  );
    
}

countDataToRecord(countData) {
  return countData.reduce(
    (acc, {data, value}) => {
      acc[data] = value;
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );
}
```

You can then test this by putting

```html
<pre>{countsListing | async | json}</pre>
```

in your template. No need for `.subscribe()`, no need to worry about unsubscribing.

Answer (score -1):

Since TS is async and I'm somewhat new, I don't know ways to store the subscribed variable globally, but managed to store it in an array for usage. Had to create a new API...

```
getCountData():Observable<any>
  {
    return this._http.get(`${this.castapi}/pie`)
  }
```

...with a new SQL query

```
SELECT column AS data, COUNT(*) AS value FROM table GROUP BY column ORDER BY column
```

... which returned an array with the format

```
{
   "data": "random string",
   "value": 10
}
```

which is then used as such...

```
single = [];
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.service.getCountData().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res,"data arr");
      this.single = res.data.map((array: { data: any; value: any; }) => ({ name: array.data, value: array.value }))
    });
  }
```

Sorry if it's a bit underwhelming, not that experienced in TS and just wanted to play around with ngx charts using API data.